# iOS MasterDetail app inside TabController - where to start?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uistoryboard

Really basic question here:

I want to build an app that has a bunch of MasterDetail views that can be accessed from a TabView.

I'd like to start with the MasterDetail project template, but if I do that and toss a TabController onto  the front of the storyboard, I get a crash.

```
2012-04-08 12:51:21.205 SMToolkit[22630:fb03] -[UISplitViewController topViewController]:   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x82491c0
2012-04-08 12:51:21.208 SMToolkit[22630:fb03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UISplitViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x82491c0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x16ad022 0x183ecd6 0x16aecbd 0x1613ed0 0x1613cb2 0x2bf9 0x16386 0x17274 0x26183 0x26c38 0x1a634 0x1597ef5 0x1681195 0x15e5ff2 0x15e48da 0x15e3d84 0x15e3c9b 0x16c65 0x18626 0x2a6d 0x29d5)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

All I've done so far is in the storyboard (literally I made a new MasterDetail project, then went into the storyboard and put a tabcontroller in front of it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is that the template provided for you in Master Detail includes some code you probably don't want.

In AppDelegate.m look for the following method and simply have it `return YES;`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```